# FileIOException in Blackberry

Tags: exception, blackberry, java-me

I am having a fileIOException: File system out of resources when i tried to read some files on my blackberry torch. What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Add some code to your question so that we can investigate your state and give you suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have too many files open simultaneously, or you haven't properly closed previous file connections. There is a global limit on the number of open file connections on the BlackBerry, something like 16 open at any time. You should close connections as soon as you don't need them.

Comment: I did closed all the connection. I had the exact same problem when I was using simulator then I managed to solve this. And when I am using the actual device, the same problem came back again.

Comment: Is there any way to find out at runtime how many of these 16 handles are open? (To help track down when they're opened, so that they can be closed)