# How to count how many open file resources an app has?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

This question is intended as a follow up to this question: [FileIOException in Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917579/fileioexception-in-blackberry)

I'm getting the same `out of resources` `IOException` but would like a way to internally track how many handles are open at a time. Is this possible?

Comment: In eclipse plugin there's a "BlackBerry Memory Statistics View", but I'm not sure it shows what you need.

Comment: can you Provide your code snippet here?

Comment: I've solved the problem with my open handles now, I had (as expected) just forgotten to `close()` some of them. My question still stands though of how to keep track.